# how to get these following arrays with two pointer methodology in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

input
[1,8,9]

output
[[1],[1,8],[1,8,9],[8],[8,9],[9]]

It seems like subset array but i would like to get this output with two pointer way.
let's say leftP=0, rightP=0; and then by using for loop, the rightP will increase up to the end of array until there's no more elements and then leftP move by 1...

1 -> [1], [1,8],[1,8,9]

8 -> [8],[8,9]

9 -> [9]

```js
function solution(arr) {
   let totalArr = [];
   let leftP = 0;

   for(let rightP=0; rightP<arr.length; rightP++) {
      totalArr.push(arr[rightP]);

      // this is where i'm kinda stuck
      while()

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this using just 2 for loop as you are doing as:

`i` is here `leftP` and `j` is here `rightP`

```js
const arr = [1, 8, 9];

const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  let temp = [arr[i]];
  result.push([...temp]);
  for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; ++j) {
    temp.push(arr[j]);
    result.push([...temp]);
  }
  temp = [];
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You can simply slice the array using the two pointers, it's way simpler!

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee Dude, Both are exactly doing same Under the hood. I am externally creating an array and you are just making JS to do it. Because slice will return a new array. Simple

Answer (score 1):

**Simply slice the array using the two pointers!**

Working solution below:

```js
const arr = [1, 8, 9];

const solution = (arr) => {
  const resArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j <= arr.length; j++) {
      resArr.push(arr.slice(i, j));
    }
  }

  return resArr;
};

console.log(solution(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just translate your logic into code, noting that you would need two nested loops.

```js
function solution(arr) {
  let totalArr = [];
  for (let left = 0; left < arr.length; left++) {
    totalArr.push([]);
    for (let right = left + 1; right <= arr.length; right++) {
      totalArr[left].push(arr.slice(left, right));
    }
  }
  return totalArr;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(solution([1, 8, 9])));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: auto;
}
```

(note that this groups them based on `left` - to make the array flat):

```js
function solution(arr) {
  let totalArr = [];
  for (let left = 0; left < arr.length; left++) {
    for (let right = left + 1; right <= arr.length; right++) {
      totalArr.push(arr.slice(left, right));
    }
  }
  return totalArr;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(solution([1, 8, 9])));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: auto;
}
```

Comment: No worries @iDevBrandon, glad I could help!

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee that's what I'm doing... `arr.slice(left, right)`?